# How to parse a line from a file which contains text separated by delimiter in batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file

Below is my code.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%i in (file.txt) do call :process %%i %%j %%k    
goto :ENDPOINT

:process    
echo %1    
echo %2
echo %3
```

file.txt contains

```
SELECT * FROM ABC;DBNAME;TABLENAME
SELECT * FROM XYZ;DBNAME;TABLENAME
SELECT * FROM PQR;DBNAME;TABLENAME
```

----------------OUTPUT---------------

```
SELECT
*
FROM
```

which is wrong ,I want it as

```
SELECT * FROM ABC
DBNAME
TABLENAME
```

Can someone please point out whats wrong.
Im new to batch scripting.

Answer (score 1):

The FOR-loop delim works as expected, but your `call` disturbs your expectation.
That's because the `CALL` splits parameters by multiple delimiter characters `<space>;=,`
To avoid this you can quote the parameters and unquote them later

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=;" %%i in (file.txt) do call :process "%%i" "%%j" "%%k"
exit /b

:process
echo %~1
echo %~2
echo %~3
exit /b
```